# PHP scripts to insert image file into mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

Am still weak on PHP,I need some help please on my scripts, I have tried to insert image and text in the table, text are well posted in the table and displayed correctly but image it shows "C:\fakepath\Logo Micro Connection Finale.jpg
" on the browser. 
I will show you step by step scripts files I used.

1: This is "managesales.php" file hold html codes

```
 <div id="tab5s">
  <div class="units-row" style="font-size: 12px">
   <table class="table table-hovered table-bordered table-striped unit-100">
    <tr class="unit-100 message message-info">
   <th colspan="2"> <font size="3px">Company/Office Creation</font></th>
   <tr class="unit-100" style="">
    <td> Name.</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"</td>*</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="unity-100" style="">
<td>Tax identification number</td>
 <td><input type="text" id="tin" name="tin"></td>
</tr>
 <tr class="unity-100" style="">
  <td> Address. </td>
  <td><input type="text" id="adress" name="adress"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
     </tr>
   <tr class="unity-100" style="">
 <td> Photo </td>
  <td><input name="FILE" value="102400" type="hidden">
 <input id="image" name="image" accept="image/jpeg" type="file">
  </td></tr><td><button class="btn btn-round " id="tupia">Save</button>
    </td>
         </table></div>
```

2: This is "footer.php" file hold javascript code

```
 $('#tupia').click(function(){
         var name   = $('#name').val();
         var tin   = $('#tin').val();
         var adress  = $('#adress').val();
         var sta  = $('#sta').val();
         var tel  = $('#tel').val();
         var mob  = $('#mob').val();
         var email  = $('#email').val();
         var curence  = $('#curence').val();
         var image  = $('#image').val();

         $('#name').removeClass('input-error');
         $('#adress').removeClass('input-error');
         $('#mob').removeClass('input-error');

         if(name=="" && adress=="" && mob==""){
             $('#name').addClass('input-error');
             $('#adress').addClass('input-error');
             $('#mob').addClass('input-error');
         }else if(name==""){
             $('#name').addClass('input-error');
         }else if(adress == ""){
             $('#adress').addClass('input-error');
         }else if(mob == ""){
             $('#mob').addClass('input-error');
         }else{
             $('<span />',{ text: 'Please waiting .' , id:'fd'}).css({'color':'red', 'padding-left':'12px', 'font-size': '12px'}).insertAfter(this);
             $('#fdpr').fadeIn();
             $.post('company_junction', {name:name, tin:tin, adress:adress, state:sta, tel:tel, mob:mob, email:email, curence:curence, image:image}, function(data){
                 var fd = $('#fd');
                 $(fd).hide();

                 var res = data;
                 if(res == 'good'){
                     $('#name').val('');
                     $('#tin').val('');
                     $('#adress').val('');
                     $('#sta').val('');
                     $('#tel').val('');
                     $('#mob').val('');
                     $('#email').val('');
                     $('#curence').val('');
                     $('#image').val('');
                     $('#fdpr').removeClass('message').removeClass('message-error');
                     $('#fdpr').addClass('message').addClass('message-success').html("Information saved successfully").fadeOut(4000);

                 }else if(res == "stop"){
                     $('#fdpr').removeClass('message').removeClass('message-success');
                     $('#fdpr').addClass('message').addClass('message-error').html("This Office name Or adress already exist").fadeOut(3000);
                 }else{
                     $('#fdpr').removeClass('message').removeClass('message-success');
                     $('#fdpr').addClass('message').addClass('message-error').html('Information not saved').fadeOut(4000);
                 }
             });


         }

     });
```

3: This is "company_junction.php" file

```
 <?php
 require_once 'incs/functions.php';
 require_once 'classes/Database.php';
 echo save_company::savecompany_info();
 ?>
```

4: The last one is "save_company.php" file, used to  post information into mysql.

```
 <?php
    class save_company{
      public static function savecompany_info(){

    global $database;

    $item = $database->escape_value($_POST['name']);
    $tn = $database->escape_value($_POST['tin']);
    $price = $database->escape_value($_POST['adress']);
    $sta = $database->escape_value($_POST['state']);
    $tel = $database->escape_value($_POST['tel']);
    $mob = $database->escape_value($_POST['mob']);
    $email = $database->escape_value($_POST['email']);
    $cure = $database->escape_value($_POST['curence']);
    $image = $database->escape_value($_POST['image']);
    $date = date('Y-m-d');

    //just check if name exist in the company_info table
    $se = "SELECT * FROM company_info";
    $QR =$database->query($se);
    $ft =$database->fetch_array($QR);
    $ans =$ft['name'];
    $ans2 =$ft['adress'];
    if($ans == $item || $ans2 == $price){
        echo "stop";
    }else{
        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO company_info VALUES('','$item','$tn','$price','$sta','$tel','$mob','$email','$cure','$image')";
        $res3 = $database->query($sql2);
        if ($res3) {
            echo "good";
        } else {
            echo "stop";
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This is mysql table fields

```
id | name | tin | adress |  image
```

A data type of image field that store image is "MEDIULBLOB".

Comment: Dont store images on the database. Store the images on disk and a filename and maybe a path to the filename  only on the database

Comment: `$_POST['image']` holds the path of the file, not the binary array of the uploaded file. Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) out

Comment: If you are uploading the image, which is how it looks, the image would be available via the $_FILES global which you would have to manipulate to get the image and from that you would need to read the file as a binary and store that data in the db - but as noted, it is better to store a reference to the file path after moving it to a known location on your server - otherwise the db will grow to a ridiculous size

Comment: RiggsFolly, Can you show me according to my scripts above how scripts will suppose to be reconstructed.

Answer (score 0):

Images are not saved in Database. Only, image path are saved in database. Through which you can show that image. Generally what you do in . So, Save this 'File Path' in table. In the below example, $RTargetPath is there, which is having Filepath. So, 'UploadImage' is a folder where your file will get saved. So, use this code. It will be helpful.

```
function GetPropertyImageExtension($imagetype)
{
   if(empty($imagetype)) return false;
   switch($imagetype)
   {
      case 'image/bmp': return '.bmp';

      case 'image/gif': return '.gif';

      case 'image/jpeg': return '.jpg';

      case 'image/png': return '.png';

      default: return false;

   }
}
if (!empty($_FILES['CustomImage']["name"]))
{   
   $file_name=$_FILES['CustomImage']["name"];
   $temp_name=$_FILES['CustomImage']["tmp_name"];
   $imgtype=$_FILES['CustomImage']["type"];
   $ext= GetPropertyImageExtension($imgtype);
   $imagename=date("d-m-Y")."-".time().$ext;

   $Rtarget_path = "UploadImage/".$imagename;
   if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['CustomImage']['tmp_name'], $Rtarget_path ))
   {
      [..SQL Query..]
   }
}
```

Comment: you can store images in a db in a blob column

Comment: Yeah. We Can. @RamRaider.

Answer (score 0):

Storing images in Database is not recommended for MySQL systems. , Because it will create unnecessary overhead in your system.  If you really want to store the image in your mysql database see this [Tutorial](http://forgetcode.com/PHP/539-Photo-Upload-and-Retrive-with-MySql-using-BLOB)